# Message Extension doesn't load task modules in Microsoft Teams Android app

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a message extension that uses Task Module and Adaptive Cards which allows users to select from a ChoiceSet or enter input text. It's working fine on desktop and iOS devices but when I try it out on Android, the task module doesn't show up.

I am handling the inputs usingTeamsActivityHandler.handleTeamsMessagingExtensionSubmitAction and TeamsActivityHandler.handleTeamsMessagingExtensionFetchTask.

```
"composeExtensions": [
{
  "botId": "<<BOT-ID>>",
  "commands": [
    {
      "id": "createTicket",
      "type": "action",
      "description": "Command to run action to create a Ticket from Compose Box",
      "title": "Create Ticket",
      "context": ["compose"],
      "fetchTask": true,
      "initialRun": true
    },
    {
      "id": "addComment",
      "type": "action",
      "description": "Add comment",
      "title": "Add Comment",
      "context": ["message"]
    },
    {
      "id": "createTicketFromMessage",
      "type": "action",
      "description": "Create ticket",
      "title": "Create a ticket",
      "context": ["message"]
    }
  ]
}
```

]

Comment: Are you trying action based messaging extension or search based messaging extension?

Comment: We are tried with Action Based messaging extension. It's working fine with android app.
https://youtube.com/shorts/PVhk-chUI7Q

Teams Version-1416/1.0.0.2022395202/1027
Sample link-https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/51.teams-messaging-extensions-action

Comment: Yes, we are using an action-based message extension. It is working fine from the plus sign of the chat box but if the same command has also a "message" context or it has only a "message" context and then we use that message extension on the specific message from its More options >> More actions >> Select action, modal doesn't open.

Comment: We are checking the above scenario as well. It's working with android App-
https://youtube.com/shorts/U6_QgL3fS7Y?feature=share
Could please try with provided sample?

Comment: I've attached my composeExtensions above in the description. The last command with id 'createTicketFromMessage' and context 'message' is causing issues on Android devices.

Comment: What I've figured out as yet is that if I add parameters to this command in the manifest then it works fine but the form renders with empty data. I want to load a form field populated with message body text in it which I was doing in handleTeamsMessagingExtensionSubmitAction function in my bot code but if I add parameters in the manifest command then I don't receive the request in handleTeamsMessagingExtensionSubmitAction function and form gets rendered with empty fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed that I had 2 different commands with the same title in my manifest which was causing this issue. Currently, it looks working fine by updating my manifest.